# Schroeder's Thermal Physics: Numerical Analysis for a Two State Paramagnet

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

In chapter 3 of Schroeder's Thermal Physics, the following table is given on pp. 100.

[image]

For the case of $N = 100$, the table shows values of various dimensionless quantities related to the multiplicity of a two-state non interacting para magnet. I get all but the last two columns. How have these expressions been derived for $T$ and $C$?

Note that Schroeder derives the closed form analytical expressions for $\Omega$, $T$ etc.

---

Comment: The text explicitly says that the table shows those values "calculated [...] as explained in the text". Is there really no explanation in the text?

Comment: @Sanya it says that the values are calculated from the expressions which are derived from the relevant derivatives "as explained in the text." I am not really sure how to get those expressions from the derivatives? See the edit to my post, though.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question fully, which can only be done by making a list of the earlier expressions and then following how he alters them.

The sixth column of the table uses T = $\Delta U$/$\Delta S$.  He subtracts the values in the preceding row from those in the following row.

So .47 is [-96-(-100)]/[8.51-0]

In  the last column he uses C = $\Delta U$/$\Delta T$

So try finding C  with the same idea, the "centred difference approximation".

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not explicitly written for paramagnet, you can refer equation 3.10 on page 91 where internal energy and temperature are related for T and refer equation 3.15 on page 92 for specific heat. And problem 3.24 tells you how to do calculation as well.